# Fulltext MySQL com Spring Boot

Tags: mysql, jpa, spring-boot

Bom dia, estou tentando fazer um fulltext no mysql com spring boot, no mysql quando faço o teste com o comando de sql, o resultado trás corretamente, porém quando passo no spring boot o sql native, ele trás uma lista vazia.

PositionRepository

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT * FROM position WHERE MATCH (name, area) AGAINST (':description' IN BOOLEAN MODE)")
List<Position> searchByNameAndArea(@Param("description") String name);
```

PositionService

```
public List<Position> searchByNameAndArea(String name) {
    return positionRepository.searchByNameAndArea(name);
}
```

PositionController

```
@GetMapping("/search")
public List<Position> searchByNameAndArea(@RequestParam String name) {
    return positionService.searchByNameAndArea(name);
}
```

Depois que eu rodo o projeto, entro no banco e rodo o comando

```
ALTER TABLE position ADD FULLTEXT (NAME, AREA);
```

URL usada no Postman

```
localhost:8080/position/search?name=position
```

Model da Position

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "position")
public class Position {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@EqualsAndHashCode.Include
private Long id;

@NotNull
private String name;

@NotNull
private String area;

}
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar, fazendo favor.

Comment: Como esta o mapeamento da classe Position

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta com a Model.

Comment: Pelo que percebi o o comando sql não está conseguindo pegar o name que passo como parâmetro, porque se eu deixa com a palavra automática sem parâmetro, ele consegue trazer o resultado.

Comment: @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT * FROM position WHERE MATCH (name, area) AGAINST ('position' IN BOOLEAN MODE)")

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde pessoal,

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT * FROM position WHERE MATCH (name, area) AGAINST (':description' IN BOOLEAN MODE)")
List<Position> searchByNameAndArea(@Param("description") String name);
```

Consegui resolver o meu problema, no AGAINST (:description IN BOOLEAN MODE) não precisa das aspas simples na palavra :description, retirando ela, o resultado aparece corretamente.

Comment: Assim tb funciona : SELECT * FROM position WHERE MATCH (name, area) AGAINST (?1 IN BOOLEAN MODE)